# Google Earth Engine: summary statistics of an image by another image classified

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification, feature-collection, region, summary

I want to summarize the value from one image by the label provided by another classified image which only with two labels. But the reduceRegions function needs the FeatureCollection to provide the label. Could I directly use the image to provide the label?

When I convert the image to FeatureCollection which produce too many features, which then can't be used in reduceRegions. Could I merge the features with the same label to one feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on if your first image contains continuous or categorical values. Assuming that you have a continuous data in first image and you want to summarize it based on second image with two categories (0,1), you can do something like this:

```
// some data for an example
var hansen = ee.Image("UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2020_v1_8"),
    roi = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[103.95526453721641, -3.9735955563113525],
          [103.95526453721641, -4.406394611083949],
          [104.52930018174766, -4.406394611083949],
          [104.52930018174766, -3.9735955563113525]]], null, false);
 
// just some image with two categories "another classified image"    
var another_classified = hansen.select("loss").eq([0,1])
Map.addLayer(another_classified)

// image with continuous values between 0 and 1 hansen.select("treecover2000").divide(100)
var res = hansen.select("treecover2000").divide(100)
// to split the image into two images based on "another classified image with two categories"
.multiply(another_classified)
// preparing the data and applying a reducer 
.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion({
  geometry: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum()
})

print(res)
```

Working script is here:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/5b90fbb36501a7a113a3f3ea500dff85

It would be helpful if the next time when you ask question, you can provide a working example and more context about what kind of data you are dealing with. In that way, you can get a better help.

I hope this useful. Good luck with your analysis!

Comment: Thank you ,it is useful!